# Windows XP localhost as MySQL server alias

Tags: mysql, windows-xp, hostname

I'm on the road at the moment and just had a thought

I have a Windows XP Virtual Machine installed with Delphi and a local MySQL server set up with copies of the "live" databases back in the office.

I'd like to be able to use the local db in place of the "live" one if I'm offline.

At the moment in Delphi I have "local" connections set up, but these are only any use within Delphi.  And often lead to issues if I forget to switch back to the live connection when I get back to the office.

Is there any way I can fool Windows into thinking that the local MySQL server is in fact the office server if it can't reach the office server?  Can it spoof two server names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the `hosts` file in `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` which will allow you to make any requests to `server.fqdn` go to `127.0.0.1`

http://kb.simplywebhosting.com/idx/0/045/article/

e.g. a request to `servername.domain.tld` using MySQL connection strings will redirect to your local DB.

You will still need to remember to change this back when you get to the office...

(If you have delphi on the laptop though, why not create a simple service which edits the hosts file based upon whether the server is reachable or not.)

Comment: I knew about the hosts file - editing that manually has similar risk / work issues as the current setup... Service is interesting, but I'm probably not on the road enough to warrent it!